# How to translate an image?

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, microsoft-office, translation

I have some Chinese documents in PDF format, the pages unfortunately are scanned, so the   word-by-word translation no longer become an option :( .

Yesterday I came across Microsoft Office Document Imaging [in this blog post](http://cnedelcu.blogspot.com/2012/01/chinese-ocr-translating-scanned-or.html), everything went good, except that I've remembered I have no Chinese language support.

So what can I do to solve this, are there any other possible alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to [install a language pack](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/do-i-need-a-language-pack-or-language-interface-pack-HA010354264.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA010354783) to enable Chinese langauge support in Word; once that's done, the method described in the linked post looks like it should work, if somewhat less than perfectly due to the nature of OCR. (I'd recommend that, instead of scanning to JPEG as the post describes, that you scan directly to TIFF, which is a lossless format, and at the highest resolution your scanner can support -- the more information you can supply the OCR routine, the better the results you'll get from it.)

Comment: the packs are for $$  , that's exactly what i am looking for another alternative ...

Comment: @Higet Unfortunately, I think the only alternative is to come up with an entirely different toolchain.

Comment: the packages are easily obtained in torr websites , the problem is that they come usually in huge volumes - i heard also about JOCR  - ; otherwise thanks , and waiting for the vote option to be enabled :) .